# Remove default settings from fieldset basic in module

Tags: module, module-params

Is it possible to remove the default settings (sidebar) in **fieldset name="basic"** (Display title, module position, state etc...) and put them in a separate custom tab?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These specific fields are hardcoded in the layout so using a form plugin to move them around won't work. To make any changes you'd have to create a template override. Copy

```
administrator/components/com_modules/views/module/tmpl/edit.php
```

To

```
administrator/templates/your_template/html/com_modules/module/edit.php
```

And customize it to your liking.